# upload form with other form fiels angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-fileupload

```js
        'use strict';
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

            $scope.val1 = 'Sr. Python Developer';
            $scope.val2 = 'Jr. Python Developer';
            $scope.val3 = 'Sr. UI Developer';
            $scope.val4 = 'Jr. UI developer';
            $scope.val5 = 'Sr. Android Developer';
            $scope.val6 = 'Jr. Android Developer';
            $scope.val7 = 'Sr. Tester';
            $scope.val8 = 'Jr. Tester';
            $scope.val9 = 'Sr. Devops Engineer';
            $scope.val10 = 'Graphic designer';
            
            $scope.submitForm = function() {
                console.log('clicked')
                $scope.resume = document.getElementById('resume').files[0];
                
                var promise = $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'contactus.php',
                    data: {
                        'name': $scope.name,
                        'phone': $scope.phone,
                        'experience': $scope.experience,
                        'email': $scope.email,
                        'position': $scope.position,
                        'resume': $scope.resume
                    },
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                });

                promise.then(function(response) {
                    var request = response.data;
                    if (request.success == "true") {
                        alert("Thank you for getting in touch with Mohar");

                        var inst = $('[data-remodal-id=modal]').remodal();
                        inst.close();

                        $scope.name = '';
                        $scope.phone = '';
                        $scope.experience = '';
                        $scope.email = '';
                        $scope.position = val
                        $scope.resume = '';
                        $scope.userForm.$setPristine();
                        $scope.userForm.$setUntouched();
                    } else {
                        alert("Please try after sometime");
                        window.location.href = 'career.html';
                    }
                });

            }
        });


        app.directive('validFile', ['$parse', function($parse) {
            return {
                require: 'ngModel',
                link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
                    //change event is fired when file is selected
                    el.bind('change', function() {

                        //file type validation
                        let file = event.target.files[0];
                        if (file.type == 'application/pdf' || file.type == 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' || file.type == 'application/msword') {
                            if (file.size <= 1024000) {
                                console.log('file success', file);
                                //enable submit button
                                scope.$apply(function() {
                                    ngModel.$setViewValue(el.val());
                                    ngModel.$render();
                                })
                            } else {
                                console.log('file size too large')
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log('not supported file type');
                        }

                    })
                }
            }
        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        
<form name="userForm" class="job-form" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-payment" ng-model="name" name="name" id="name" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="20" placeholder="Full Name" required />
                    <div ng-show="userForm.name.$dirty && userForm.name.$invalid || userForm.name.$touched">
                        <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.required">Please enter name</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.name.$error.pattern">Please enter valid name</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-payment" ng-model="phone" name="phone" id="number" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" placeholder="Phone Number" required />
                    <div ng-show="userForm.phone.$dirty && userForm.phone.$invalid || userForm.phone.$touched">
                        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.required">Please enter contact number</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.minlength">Please enter minimum 10 digit</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.phone.$error.maxlength || userForm.phone.$error.pattern">Please enter valid contact number</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-payment" ng-model="experience" name="experience" id="experience" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" placeholder="Experience" required />
                    <div ng-show="userForm.experience.$dirty && userForm.experience.$invalid || userForm.experience.$touched">
                        <p ng-show="userForm.experience.$error.required">Please enter total experience</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.experience.$error.pattern">Please enter only numbers</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-payment" name="email" ng-model="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required />
                    <div ng-show="userForm.email.$dirty && userForm.email.$invalid || userForm.email.$touched">
                        <p ng-show="userForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</p>
                        <p ng-show="userForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-payment" id="position" ng-model="position" ng-readonly="true" placeholder="Position" required />
                    <!-- <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" placeholder="e.g: UI DEVELOPER" required> -->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <!-- <label for="resume">Upload Resume <span>*</span></label> -->
                    <input type="file" class="form-control form-control-payment" valid-file ng-model="resume" id="resume" required>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit pull-right" ng-click="submitForm()" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

hello, I am using angularjs for validation & HTTP call. I want to upload a file with some other form data like name, phone, email & file. I have done all validation which checks file size, file type etc & other basic validation & it works fine. but when I submit data it sends an empty file. I don't understand what is wrong with this code please help. thank you in advance.

Comment: Files can't be attached to JSON. Either POST the file directly (recommended) or use the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) (not recommended for large files).

Comment: I am sending data object to the server then how can I send a file independently